# maximum length of Digital Object Identifier?

Tags: database, doi

I want to add a field to my database that stores [DOIs](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Digital_object_identifier). But I can't seem to find out what their maximum length is. Does anyone know if there is a maximum length?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

never mind, I found it:

https://www.doi.org/the-identifier/resources/handbook/1_introduction#1.6.3

> DOI names have two components, known as the prefix and the suffix. These are separated by a forward slash. The two components together form the DOI name:
>
> 10.1000/123456
>
> In this example, the prefix is "10.1000" and the suffix is "123456".
>
> There is no technical limitation on the length of either the prefix or the suffix; in theory, at least, there is an infinite number of DOI names available.

Comment: I have no idea, this was at my former employer and I have no hope of remembering almost-10-year-old technical details.

Comment: Oops, I think I looked at the edited date and not the answered date. My bad. Still brings up an interesting question -- at least for someone new to databases like me -- where the spec is so lenient and reality appears to be much more limited.

Answer (score 14):

From a 100K sample, I would go for 255 as max length to be on the safe side...

On the y-axis the length of the DOI and on the x-axis you have the count of DOIs. So, we have 20k DOIs out of 100K that have a DOI length of ~63 or more.

[image]

Comment: can you specify what's on the `x` and what's on the `y`?